# Wordpress Custom Post - Reading Back Into Page

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type titled "Tea" it is the default post layout. The value of "32" is entered into the WYSIWYG editor.

I am looking through the data and I'd like to echo the_content(); into an hidden field. Which then creates a number counter based on the value of that field.

At the moment I am just getting the value of "0"

My code for it is as follows :

```
<div class="tea-count">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'tea');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  echo '
   <div id="counter">
    <input type="text" name="counter-value" value="the_content();" />
   </div>';
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

How do I get the value out to read 32, rather than 0?

That amount will change depending on what is entered by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use get_the_content(), because the_content() has built-in functions to print to the screen, and you're already inside an `echo`.

Also, you might need to change your single quotes to doubles and vice versa, or concatenate your string better.

This might work:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $content = get_the_content();
  echo '
   <div id="counter">
    <input type="text" name="counter-value" value="' . $content . '" />
   </div>';
```

Comment: Perfect. I always seem to have issues with the_content and get_the_content. I did need it to strip the tags from it, So this has done the trick.

Thanks @Chris Fletcher